# plot a point on polyline toward or away from end point(latitude longitude)

Tags: java, android, latitude-longitude, osmdroid

ive been looking for a while and cannot find solution
so I am trying to find a point on a polyline that is either a certain distance toward the opposite point or away from the main point.(I have pictures) if you are familiar with celestial navigation this is called the intercept method. so here is the almost working code.

```
       double distance = ap.distanceToAsDouble(gp)*0.00053996;
       double convert = nauticalMiles;
       double t = convert / distance;
       double actlon = ((1 - t)*ap.getLongitude() + t*gp.getLongitude());
       double actlat = ((1 - t)*ap.getLatitude() + t*gp.getLatitude());
       bear = ap.bearingTo(new GeoPoint(actlat,actlon));
       actual = ap.destinationPoint(nauticalMiles/0.00053996,bear);
```

so "ap" is the point that the point I am trying to find will be (nauticalMiles) "away" or "toward" the "gp" and they are correct so "bear" is the angle kind of from ap to gp that almost works completely. "actual" is the point I am trying to find. here is an image of how this works out.
[image]

as you can see th actual point is toward the gp point from the ap point denoted with the yellow polyline. BUT!!!! if you look at the picture the yellow line is not exactly on the red line so I think that it is off a bit. so I tried to do

```
bear = ap.bearingTo(gp);
actual = ap.destinationPoint(nauticalMiles/0.00053996,bear);
```

instead doing that whole calculation that was in the code sample previously which should work but I am getting this

[image]

which is totally off it is not on the line. so for right now I am sticking with the first approach because it is relatively accurate but that is why I am asking this question. What calculation could I do to make the yellow line exactly on the red line? I am trying to get the most accurate calculation that I can get. thank you for your time.